# Wrong answer in circle

Tags: c++

I have written simple program in c++.
It increases variable with a step 0.1. But when x should be equal 0, it is -1.38778e-16
How to solve it?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = -1;
    double y = 1;
    double step = 0.1;
    
    while (x < y){
        cout << x << endl;
        x += step;
    }
}
```

It increases variable with a step 0.1. But when x should be equal 0, it is -1.38778e-16

Comment: The way I'd solve it is by using a whole number for the step, and not a fractional number.  And, in this case, divide by 10 when interpreting the accumulated number.

Comment: Where possible with floating point numbers you should avoid incremental calculations as the rounding errors will accumulate, in your case you can just calculate the value at each step: https://godbolt.org/z/ME8Ws8Wr8. Note that none of your values are exact as `0.1` isn't representable by a `double`: https://godbolt.org/z/P3hT5zshc